# Calculate the percentage of a number in PHP laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to print a discount amount from the discount percentage. For example, if I put manually these values .i can print 150 as the discount amount. if I assign the variables it will be shown 0

```
Manual 
$ActualPrices=400
$percentToGet=37.50%
$percentInDecimal = $percentToGet / 100;
$percentamnt= $percentInDecimal * $ActualPrices;

Assigning to Variables

$perc=0;
$ActualPrices=$value->ActualPrice;
$percentToGet = $perc;
$percentInDecimal = $percentToGet / 100;
$percentamnt= $percentInDecimal * $ActualPrices;
$data['data']['products'][]=[
'percentamnt'=>$percentamnt,
 ];
      }
```

Comment: _“if I assign the variables it will be shown 0”_ - well what did you expect, when you start with `$perc=0` here? You then assign that to `$percentToGet`, which you then divide by 100 - zero divided by anything will still be zero. And then you multiple that zero by the actual price - and you seriously expect anything _but_ zero now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code block where the average can be calculated, it is a solution option

```
$item=200;
$numeroVotos=5000;
$percent = round($item/$numeroVotos*100);
if ($percent<=100){ 
    echo $percent;
}
else {
    echo "100"; 
}
```

Comment: Migue Cortés can you put this in my code am new into prgrming

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.